# Android Encoding for this character set

Tags: android, text, utf-8, character-encoding

I am getting the html text from the website. this site return the character  which like is shown in the below figure. I tried to find the character set from site, it found `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">`

[image]

It show the **output** on device after set in the text view like:

[image]

I tried some coding but doesn't effect the text,which is shown below:

```
    final Charset windowsCharset = Charset.forName("windows-1252");
    final Charset utfCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    final CharBuffer windowsEncoded = windowsCharset.decode(ByteBuffer
            .wrap(ne.scrape_detail_article_text.getBytes()));
    final byte[] utfEncoded = utfCharset.encode(windowsEncoded).array();
    // System.out.println(new String(utfEncoded, utfCharset.displayName()));

    String s = "" ;
    try {
        // String s = new String(utfEncoded, utfCharset.displayName());

        //String s = new String(texttoencoding.getBytes("windows-1252"),"UTF-8");

        s = URLEncoder.encode(texttoencoding, "windows-1252");

        Log.e("LOG", "Encoded >> " + s);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
    }

  TextviewToset.setText(Html.fromHtml(texttoencoding);
    TextviewToset.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Please Help me, how can I encode this text into `UTF-8` And display in the textview?**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are dealing with HTML-Entites here. Therefore you have to decode the HTML Entities via:

```
String text = HTML.fromHtml(yourText).toString();
```

This will give you the correct UTF-8 characters. The documentation for `Html.fromHtml()` is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It is working perfectly fine for me. Obviously in my tests i had to skip the <?> from the input. Please edit the question and include the web code as text so I can copy it

Comment: This is what I get (first parts): फेडररला हरवून जोकोविच अजिंक्य
        इंडियन वेल्स एटीपी मास्टर्स टेनिस
        इंडियन वेल्स, दि. १७ (वृत्तसंस्था) - जागतिक टेनिस क्रमवारीत दुसर्‍या क्रमांकावर असलेल्या सर्बियाच्या नोवाक जोकोविचने रोमहर्षक लढतीत रॉजर फेडररचा पराभव करून इंडियन वेल्स एटीपी मास्टर्स या टेनिस स्पर्धेच्या जेतेपदावर मोहर उमटवली. जोकोविचचे हे या वर्षातील पहिले जेतेपद ठरले हे विशेष.
        जोकोविचने अंतिम फेरीत फेडररचे आव्हान ३-६, ६-३, (oh, it's tennis ;)